# Custom editor (lexer in Aptana Studio), for unsupported languages

Tags: syntax, editor, aptana, syntax-highlighting

I know it is possible to connect some file extensions with existing editors (syntax rules). But how can I create my own editor for some exotic language which doesn't fit to current editors? I think about Shpaml. I tried to install shpaml-colorer (https://github.com/occulens/shpaml-colorer), but I can't get it to work.